# print html of the website after loadFinished signal in PyQt4. Python

Tags: python, webkit, pyqt4

I'just started learning PyQt4, and playing with signals and slots,
Please help me to fix my code in such a way that after site is fully downloaded, it will print html of this webpage. Right now it just stops after "load finished"

my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python2.7

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys

class Browser(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        QObject.__init__(self)
    def print_percent(self, percent):
        print percent
    def print_load_finished(self):
        print 'Load Finished'
        self.print_html
    def print_html(self, ok):
        frame = QWebView.page().mainFrame()
        print unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebView()
    br = Browser()
    url = QUrl('http://python.org')
    view.loadFinished.connect(br.print_load_finished)
    view.loadProgress.connect(br.print_percent)
    view.load(url)
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `print_html` method e.g.

```
 def print_load_finished(self):
        print 'Load Finished'
        self.print_html()
```

note `()` at the end of `print_html`

BUT then it still won't work anyway as your `print_html` doesn't have access to view, you can pass view to it, but it not a right way to do Object oriented programming. You should be deriving Browser from may be `QWebView` and bind to events in `__init__`, so it should be something like this

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
import sys

class Browser(QWebView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.loadFinished.connect(self.print_load_finished)
        self.loadProgress.connect(self.print_percent)

    def print_percent(self, percent):
        print percent

    def print_load_finished(self):
        print 'Load Finished'
        self.print_html()

    def print_html(self):
        frame = self.page().mainFrame()
        print unicode(frame.toHtml()).encode('utf-8')

if __name__=='__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    br = Browser()
    url = QUrl('http://python.org')
    br.load(url)
    br.show()
    app.exec_()
```